# Creating your own request to Payapl

Tags: php, paypal

I am integrating Paypal into a website I am creating. I don't need a lot of the functionality that comes with the API's and I am supporting multiple gateways. I have created my own class to handle the other gateways, however I cannot find out how to send the information. For example:

For authorize, they receive an XML object formatted in a specific way. I gather the required user information, create my own XML object with the proper information and formatting, and send this to Authorize using a curl method.

when trying to decipher the Paypal API I found it confusing with a large amount of dependencies. Is there some place that has the information I am looking for, or has someone already created their own Paypal kit and would point me in the right direction?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I found what I was looking for a while back and have been meaning to answer this question in case others were having the same issue.

what you are looking for is the paypal NVP API.
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/NVPAPIOverview/

There is also a soap style api as well.

specifically I was interested in the following operations:

- DoDirectPayment
- SetRecurringPaymentsProfile
- CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile

and for express checkout:

- SetExpressCheckout
- SetExpressCheckoutRecurring
- GetExpressCheckoutDetails
- DoExpressCheckoutPayment

if you google paypal nvp *insert operation here* that will take you to a development page that will give you key value info.

Hope this helps anyone who was in my shoes.